# How to show just one login or logout button in flask and jinjia2 template?

Tags: python, html, flask, jinja2

I want to show log out button when user is loged in and login button when user is loged out.But the buttons show as many times as I have users. How can I fix it?

```
--html code 
          {% for user in users %}
            {% if user.user_id == session['user_id'] %}
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="/logout">Logout &nbsp;</a>
            </li>
            {% elif user.user_id != session['user_id'] %}
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="/login_register">Login &nbsp;</a>
            </li> 
            {% endif %}
          {% endfor %}

--server.py code
          @app.route('/')
          def landing():

          mysql = connectToMySQL('comfort_zone')
          query = "Select user_id from users"
          users = mysql.query_db(query)
          return render_template('index.html',users=users)
```

Comment: When the user is not logged in, what is `session['user_id']`? Is it empty or None?

Comment: @Rina5, just curious, why are iterating through list of user, when only one user is logged in at a time?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to check if the user in session is present in users, then show a logout button, otherwise show a logout button. Fixed code:

`index.html`:

```
{% if logged_in %}
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="/logout">Logout &nbsp;</a>
    </li>
{% else %}
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="/login_register">Login &nbsp;</a>
    </li> 
{% endif %}
```

`server.py`

```py
@app.route('/')
def landing():
    mysql = connectToMySQL('comfort_zone')
    query = "Select user_id from users"
    users = mysql.query_db(query)
    logged_in = session['user_id'] in (user.user_id for user in users)
    return render_template('index.html', logged_in=logged_in)
```

Answer (score -1):

Depending on how `session['user_id']` is set, I would do it like this:

```
{% if session['user_id'] %}
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="/logout">Logout &nbsp;</a>
    </li>
{% else %}
    <li class="nav-item">
       <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="/login_register">Login &nbsp;</a>
    </li> 
{% endif %}
```

Basically, if the `user_id` is set in the session (i.e. somebody is logged in), show the logout button.

Comment: this might work, however, you're showing logout even if the user stored in `session['user_id']` doesn't actually exist. If you choose to use this, you don't have to query the database at all.

Comment: That is true but the OP has not specify yet, how `session['user_id']`is actually set and whether one needs to check whether the user exists or not. That's why I asked in the comment.

Comment: @Rina5 consider this scenario: user creates an account and logs in on his laptop. His ID gets stored in session. Then he logs in on his smartphone and deletes his account. When he opens his laptop again, the user_id of his deleted account is still in session, so the code of this answer would still show logout, while he is actually not logged in. Look at my answer, which handles that case